# Building a request based twitter oracle on the Solana blockchain

Tags: oracles

I am trying to understand how in principle someone might build an Oracle for Solana that works on a request basis.  A simple example would be  that someone passes the id of a tweet to a program, that then goes and gets the text from that tweet using a twitter oracle running off chain.

Right now the only way that I can think to do that is via multiple transactions.  I.e:

transaction 1 - user sends tweet id to the program

transaction 2 - a monitoring server running off chain sees that transaction, pulls the tweet from the twitter api, and pushes it to some storage on chain

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this within a single transaction? For oracles that just publish data feeds one can always just query the  most recent value within the same transaction as you want to use it.. but in this case the user is asking for some specific information that needs to be explicitly fetched, so i'm not sure if that is even possible.

Thanks!